# Lazyload plugin not working in Safari?

Tags: jquery-plugins, safari, lazy-loading

I am using the LazyLoad plugin on a column of images and it works fine in Chrome and Firefox but its messing up in Safari 5.1.7. When scrolling past the fold images are looping within the first `data-original`. Any ideas why?

```
$(function() {
  $("img.scale-with-grid").lazyload({
      effect : "fadeIn",
  });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Try setting the css for the images to display:block.